# Bootstrap grid causes vertical overflow into other divs

Tags: html, css, overflow, twitter-bootstrap-4

There is a lot of code in this one, so I'm going to put it in a codepen.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMyQEJ

Basically I am using @media queries to extend the `#about` div to be taller as my content is literally going into another div on mobile devices. I need the blue background to extend below the placeholder image so it's all in the same section.

Media Query:

```
   /*MOBILE SUPPORT*/
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #about {
    height: 120vh !important;
      background: rgb(12, 18, 71);
      background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the height to `auto`

```
/*MOBILE SUPPORT*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #about {
      height: auto !important;
      background: rgb(12, 18, 71);
      background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! This answer worked perfectly. In addition, I also added some code to the image element for a bottom margin.

Comment: I recommend that you use padding in the about section instead.